# ¿Cómo detectar el idioma del navegador con Vue JS 2?

Tags: vue.js

Recién estoy entrando en el mundo de `VueJS` y me gustaría **¿Cómo detectar el idioma del navegador?** ya que en base a esto deseo ejecutar un metodo en `VueJS`, en `Javascript` se que lo puedo hacer de esta forma:

```js
if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
var lenguage = navigator.language;
else
var lenguage = navigator.browserLanguage;
if (lenguage.indexOf('en') > -1){
 alert('Ingles');
}
else if (lenguage.indexOf('es') > -1){
 alert('Español');
}
else if (lenguage.indexOf('fr') > -1){
  alert('Frances');
}
else if (lenguage.indexOf('pt') > -1){
  alert('Portugues');
}
else{
  alert('Otro');  
}
```

Pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo en VueJS y no encuentro información al respecto.

Comment: En VueJS también puedes utilizar ese código, funcionará igualmente. Aclara un poco más tu duda.

Comment: Yo se que funcionaria pero como mencione en la pregunta necesite que se ejecute un metodo de `VueJS` al detectar el idioma del navegador por eso pregunto si se puede hacer en `VueJS`.

Comment: Puedes ejecutar tú código el las funciones de ciclo de vida de VueJS, `created` o `mounted`, depende de qué necesites. Por ejemplo: created() { var idioma = getIdioma(); // ejecutar la función dependiendo del idioma }

Comment: Ps estaba pensando como alternativa algo así como lo planteas, podrías ser tan amable de publicar una respuesta ejemplo implementando el `JS` que puse para llamar algún método 'x' de `VueJS`entiendo por `getIdioma()` que seria la función `JS` que me retornaría el resultado y en base  a eso llamaría el método de `VueJS`

Answer (score 1):

Como te he comentado, la solución sería ejecutar tú código en el hook `created`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<h1>{{idioma}}</h1>',
  data() {
    return {
      idioma: null,
      functions: {
        'es-ES'() {
          console.log('Español')
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.idioma = navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.language
    this.functions[this.idioma]()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Si lo deseas también puedes definir el idioma en data directamente. Y en alguno de los ciclos de vida de Vue que más gustes llamar a tu función.

También he movido la función a la propiedad methods de Vue.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<h1>{{idioma}}</h1>',
  data() {
    return {
      idioma: navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.language
    }
  },
  methods: {
    'es-ES'() {
      console.log('Español')
    }
  },
  created() {
    this[this.idioma]()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por darle claridad a mi vida jajajaja este ejemplo me sera de mucha utilidad, nuevamente Gracias por responder.

Comment: De nada!! Saludos!! =)